# Powermock tests fail with "Failed to transform class with name" - Maven build

Tags: java, maven, powermock, javassist

We are doing migration from Ant to Maven build, then we noticed some problems with failing tests, which working well on Ant build. Note that, we are using same bundle of libraries.

Two LightTests classes (both of them contains tests of same class) failing with error like this:
***Failed to transform class with name com.some.class. Reason: null***

I google a lot and found identical problem posted almost 4 years ago. I've got identical stacktrace like there. Unfortunately without a fix: 
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JASSIST-141

Test platform:

Java 1.80_66
Maven 3.2.5
Maven SureFire 3.18.1
Maven Compiler 3.2

Powermock-Mockito-release-full 1.62
Mockito-all 1.10.19
Javassist 3.19.0

I tried another versions of Javassist (3.18.2, 3.20.0), PowerMock and Mockito-all. No results.

Anybody knows how to solve this strange problem?

Thank's for help.

Comment: I've read issue description on jboss and it looks like an issue with big, good class. Does your `LightTests` mock some big class?

Comment: No, class is not so big as described at jboss. Class added to PrepareForTest() annotation is final and extends another abstract class which extends HttpServlet class, then finally it implements one interface. I get guess where is problem.